# How to pass custom object to app engine endpoint

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using Google App Engine Endpoints. Docs says that only primitive types like String, int and so on are supported. I want to pass an object. I read about the @ApiTransform annotation so I thought to use to convert my object from/to String object, but I'm not sure about the "scope" of this kind of annotation. Is it the right goal? Or the transform api is designed for another goal? I didn't find any example or code about a real use of this annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you can find example code for @ApiTransform

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloworld-java-maven/tree/master/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld

and some more documentation here

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/annotations

You can only return custom objects from Endpoints but not passing objects to the endpoint.

@ApiTransform can only be used for changing the object which will be returned from your endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

To clear up some potential misconceptions: You can only use primitives in path or query parameters (that is, `@Named` parameters). If you want to pass a request object in, simply specify it in your method without a `@Named` annotation, and it will be treated as the request resource.